# FTPS altered port

Tags: port, ftps

I had configured FTPS service on windows machine. It is working absolutely fine. User can access the site from browser using address **ftps://IP_Address:990** by first acknowledging the site certificate.

Now, If I change the default FTPS port 990 to say 146 then, through browser I am not able to connect to same site using the address as: **ftps://IP_Address:146**

After changing the port, I restarted the service, also restarted the machine several times. but still it is not working.

*There isn't any proxy server or firewall in between.*

**UPDATE:**
From Linux machine if I execute the command

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect IP_Address:146
```

then an error occurs saying

```
3073566400:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794
```

Comment: have you confirmed that the new port is bound to the service? from the server run either `netstat -ntlup | grep <portnum>` as root on linux, or on windows in an elevated powershell `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING | findstr <portnum>`, to confirm that your service is available. Also confirm that the service is binding to either 0.0.0.0 or the ip of the server, but definitely not 127.0.0.1. In general this comes down to the three P's: a Process running, bound to a Port that is accessible to a Pathway.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, It's typo. I corrected the question. Please refer it.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I checked on Windows machine. Said port, i.e. 146 is bounded to all three mentioned IP's i.e. 0.0.0.0, IP_Address and 127.0.0.1